# How do I edit each item in a list in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I'm trying to create an application that takes a string and converts it into Pig Latin in Python. The code I have so far is this:

```
test = "hello world"
def PigLatin():
    split_test = test.split()
    for i in split_test:
        wordlist = list(i)
        wordlist.append(i[0])
        return wordlist
print PigLatin()
```

I'm attempting to take the first character of each word and append it to the end of said word. However, when I run the code it only edits "hello" or "world" depending on the location of the return statement. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return statement causes your function to exit and hand back a value to its caller. So, return statement in your for loop sends a value back to the PigLatin function call, and is done, out of the stack. Also, [read this please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/why-would-you-use-the-return-statement-in-python).
Code:

```
test = "hello world"
def PigLatin():
    ret = []
    split_test = test.split()
    for i in split_test:
        wordlist = list(i)
        wordlist.append(i[0])
        ret.append(wordlist)
    return ret
print PigLatin()
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure where the return statement should be, and I tried that location, but it was only returning the word "worldw". After trying out your code I realized that the empty list you created was necessary as well.

Comment: If the answer did help you, please accept it. Green motivates! :)